# Django admin: 'add' page, want to add multiple objects on one page

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = fields.CharField()
```

In admin, I want to display multiple forms for Country so I can add multiple different country objects at once. I don't know where to start? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Since the number of countries is more or less ... *constant* you might not want to store them as objects at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do this inside the admin. The admin is a ready-made interface for editing single objects (and, optionally, multiple objects *related* to that object), but doesn't give you any way to edit multiple objects at once.

If you need this, write your own view using a formset.

Comment: I think gladysbixly's answer would work as well, but a custom view and formset would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is you could extend the admin template change_form.html to display a formset, and have the 'add' url point to a view that would handle the page rendering. You will also need to override the url in your urls.py. Not the best but it would work.