# Adding multiple model objects at a time in the Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to allow my django admin users to add multiple objects at a time for one of my models in addition to the one-object-at-a-time standard approach used by the django admin.

I am considering modifying the change_form.html template for the model so that it uses a formset [(as suggested here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048188/django-admin-add-page-want-to-add-multiple-objects-on-one-page) -- although I am not sure how to implement this yet.

Note that I am not adding multiple child objects so I cannot use inlines for this.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You can always make a custom admin view that uses a formset for your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

Comment: you can create your own form for admin to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form